# Combining Tables With Different Data Using Linq in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Two classes Named OfflineOrderLineItem.cs and OnlineOrderLineItem.cs  both have diff Order table named offline and Online

In that i want to Combine the two tables data to search and Display the Fields from both tables

How to do that using linq in mvc4 ??? any idea.....

```
public virtual IPagedList<OnlineOrderLineItem> SearchOrderLineItems(string PoNumber)
{
     var query1 = (from ol in _offlineOrderLineItemRepository.Table
                   select new
                  {                            
                   ol.Name

                  }).ToList();

     var query2 = (from opv in _onlineOrderLineItemRepository.Table
                   select new
                   {
                    opv.Name

                   }).ToList();

     var finalquery = query1.Union(query2);

     if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
     finalquery = finalquery.Where(c => c.Name == Name);
     var orderlineitems = finalquery.ToList(); //its not working  it throw a error
     return new PagedList<OnlineOrderLineItem>(orderlineitems);//error 
    }
```

**Error**

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'
to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Nop.Core.Domain.Management.OnlineOrderLineItem>'
to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Nop.Core.Domain.Management.OnlineOrderLineItem>'
```

Comment: Is there any reason you use anonymous types in your select given that you only select 1 element?

Comment: its a sample code  for Reference

Comment: What is `final` ? is that a typo for `finalquery` ?

Comment: sorry i changed it please check it

Answer (score 2):

`query1` and `query2` are lists of an anonymous type with a single property of type `string`. (I assmume the `ol.Name` and `opv.Name` are `string`s.) Hence `finalQuery` and `orderlineitems` are collections of this anonymous as well. By specifying `PagedList<T>` you require that the collection passed into the constructor is an enumeration of type `T`. `T` is `OnlineOrderLineItem`, but the enumeration passed into the constructor is the anonymous type which is a different type. Result: compiler error.

To solve the problem I suggest that you define a named helper type that you can use to union the two different types `OfflineOrderLineItem` and `OnlineOrderLineItem`:

```
public class OrderLineItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PoNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // maybe more common properties of `OfflineOrderLineItem`
    // and `OnlineOrderLineItem`     
}
```

Then your `SearchOrderLineItems` method should return a paged list of that helper type:

```
public virtual IPagedList<OrderLineItemViewModel> SearchOrderLineItems(
    string PoNumber)
{
    var query1 = from ol in _offlineOrderLineItemRepository.Table
                 select new OrderLineItemViewModel
                 {
                     Id = ol.Id,
                     PoNumber = ol.PoNumber,
                     Name = ol.Name,
                     // maybe more properties
                 };
                 // don't use ToList here, so that the later Union and filter
                 // can be executed in the database

    var query2 = from opv in _onlineOrderLineItemRepository.Table
                 select new OrderLineItemViewModel
                 {
                     Id = opv.Id,
                     PoNumber = opv.PoNumber,
                     Name = opv.Name,
                     // maybe more properties
                 };
                 // don't use ToList here, so that the later Union and filter
                 // can be executed in the database

    var finalquery = query1.Union(query2);
    // again no ToList here

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PoNumber))
        finalquery = finalquery.Where(c => c.PoNumber == PoNumber);

    var orderlineitems = finalquery.ToList(); // DB query runs here

    return new PagedList<OrderLineItemViewModel>(orderlineitems);
}
```

It is important to use `ToList` only at the very end of the query. Otherwise you would load the whole tables of all `OnlineOrderLineItem`s and all `OfflineOrderLineItem`s into memory and then filter out the items with the given `PoNumber` in memory which would be a big overhead and performance desaster.

Comment: It took me forever to find this answer (not least because "model" and "view" have extremely different meanings in databases and MVC code). I'd tried something similar and am not sure how exactly my attempt differed from your example, but this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 var orderlineitems = finalquery.ToList();
```

Try

```
 var orderlineitems = finalquery.AsQueryable();
```

From https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/PagedList.cs, PagedList takes a `IQueryable<T>`

[`Queryable.AsQueryable<TElement> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: What exactly is the error? Which line causes the error? What is the type of query1, query2, and finalquery?